Join two ends of curves
I want to represent the theoretical curve defined by:

for x<Veq : \potstandfer+0.059*log10 (x/(\Veq-x))-\potref
for x>Veq : \potstandperman+0.059/5*log10 ((x-\Veq)/\Veq)-\potref

I can do these two parts separately but when I put them together, I get a gap between the end of the 1st and the beginning of the 2nd (related to the fact that the mathematical functions are not defined in x=Veq)
How could I smooth the curve in order to see the continuity?
Subsidiary question: what is the best method to display the derivative of the "total" function?
Thanks

\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript

%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\def\concentrationperm{0.02}
\def\concentrationfer{0.1}
\def\volumefer{10}
\def\potstandperman{1.51}
\def\potstandfer{0.77}
\def\potref{0.195}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Veq}{\volumefer*\concentrationfer/(5*\concentrationperm)}

\footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=25,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.75,
    xlabel={$V (\unit{\mL})$},
    ylabel={$\Delta E (\unit{\V})$},
    ytick distance=0.5,
    minor y tick num=4,
    minor x tick num=4,
    grid style={black!10},
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    axis line shift=1pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    legend pos=north west,% place de la légende,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    samples = 500,
    no markers,
    ]
    
        %avant équivalence
        \addplot expression[domain=0:\Veq, red, solid, very thin]{\potstandfer+0.059*log10 (x/(\Veq-x))-\potref};
            
    %frontiere horiz Cl2/Cl-
    \addplot expression[domain=\Veq:25, red, solid, very thin]{\potstandperman+0.059/5*log10 ((x-\Veq)/\Veq)-\potref}; 
    
        

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As you write, there's a mathematical problem at x=Veq (+-\infty). In fact, you can't and shouldn't smooth that, and the discontinuity is already visible. As an alternative draw the pole as a vertical line at x in a different color. // For the derivative the easiest thing would be to calculate it (on paper) and plot both regions.

@MS-SPO I know that it is not defined in V=Veq
I tried by adding a line to draw a quasi vertical ( \addplot[red, solid, very thin] coordinates{(\Veq, 0.91) (\Veq+0.01, 1.29)};) but it is complicated to find the connection on each side. I tell myself that I should calculate the last point of the 1st part and the first point of the 2nd part to draw the connection line but I do not see how I can do it?

To obey mathematics I'd present it like this, using axis cs: to avoid trouble from changing scales - after all, it's still TikZ:

\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript

%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\def\concentrationperm{0.02}
\def\concentrationfer{0.1}
\def\volumefer{10}
\def\potstandperman{1.51}
\def\potstandfer{0.77}
\def\potref{0.195}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Veq}{\volumefer*\concentrationfer/(5*\concentrationperm)}

\footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=25,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.75,
    xlabel={$V (\unit{\mL})$},
    ylabel={$\Delta E (\unit{\V})$},
    ytick distance=0.5,
    minor y tick num=4,
    minor x tick num=4,
    grid style={black!10},
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    axis line shift=1pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    legend pos=north west,% place de la légende,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    samples = 500,
    no markers,
    ]
    
    %avant équivalence
    \addplot expression[domain=0:\Veq, red, solid, very thin]{\potstandfer+0.059*log10 (x/(\Veq-x))-\potref};
            
    %frontiere horiz Cl2/Cl-
    \addplot expression[domain=\Veq:25, red, solid, very thin]{\potstandperman+0.059/5*log10 ((x-\Veq)/\Veq)-\potref}; 
    
    % ~~~ indicating the pole ~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     doing a little more
    \draw[dotted,line width=.9pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
    \node[anchor=north east] at (axis cs: \Veq,.2){pole};
    \node[anchor=north west] at (axis cs: \Veq,1.6){pole};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

If you want to trick the equation, you can:

introduce a small quantity q, with |q| << 0.1
chose q small enough that the red curves seems to be unchanged
add/substract q in your two equations
adjust the domains
e.g. you might chose q such that both curves meet somewhere between 0.7 V and 1.2 V (nerds might even calculate q from both equations ;-) )

